# Generar Alarmas con respecto a un dia y una hora especifica

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito crear alarmas en `android` dadas la hora, de tanto indagar intente hacerlo, me gustaria que me guiaran o me den una idea que estoy haciendo mal ya que soy noob  (al lado de muchos) y la app no me genera al notificacion en la barra de estados de android, aqui esta mi codigo

**SelectordeAlarmas.java** fragmento encargado de establecer la alarma

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.Perfil;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales.MainActivity;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Clases.AlarmaNotificacionReciver;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;


public class SelectordeAlarmas extends Fragment {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private Intent myintent;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //creamos la vista del fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_alarma, container, false);

        final AlarmManager alarma;
        //cramos las variables del layout
        Button acepalarm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaceptaralarma);
        Button boralarm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnborraralarma);
        Button cancelar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btncancelaralarma);
        //los TV
        final TextView alarmview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.avisoalarm);
        //alarma
        final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);


        //instanciamos la alarma
        alarma=(AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        //necesitamos un calendar para la seleccion de tiempo

        final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

        //implementar el metodo de aceptar alarma y cambiar aviso
        acepalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String mejorhora=String.valueOf(timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                String mejorminuto=String.valueOf(timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

                if (timePicker.getCurrentHour()<10){
                    mejorhora=String.valueOf("0"+timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                }

                if (timePicker.getCurrentMinute()<10){
                    mejorminuto=String.valueOf("0"+timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                }

                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

                myintent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmaNotificacionReciver.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),0,myintent,0);

                alarma.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

                alarmview.setText("La alarma sonara a las "+mejorhora+":"+mejorminuto);
            }
        });

        boralarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alarmview.setText("Alarma no establecida.");
            }
        });

        //implementamos el motodo del boton de cerrar sesion
        cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //establecemos un mensaje de alerta para la confirmacion
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("¿Desea cerrar sesion?");
                builder.setTitle("Alerta!");
                builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    //de ser positivo vamos al inicio y cerramo
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i= new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

**selector_alarma.xml** xml correspondiente al fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.Perfil.SelectordeAlarmas">>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Seleccione su alarma."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />


            <TimePicker
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/timePicker" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Alarma no establecida."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/avisoalarm"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:text="Aceptar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                    android:id="@+id/btnaceptaralarma"
                    android:onClick="onClickAceptarR" />
                <Button
                    android:text="Borrar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                    android:id="@+id/btnborraralarma"
                    android:onClick="onClickAceptarR" />

                <Button
                    android:text="Cancelar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btncancelaralarma"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onClickRegresar"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

vista para mejor hubicacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**AlarmaNotificacionReciver.class** clase encargada de organizar la notificacion

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.Clases;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;

/**
 * Created by Genesis on 29/01/2017.
 */

public class AlarmaNotificacionReciver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Recordatorio")
                .setContentText("Recuerda tienes trabajo")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentInfo("info");

        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
    }
}
```

llegado a este punto no se por que al momento de seleccionar una hora en el `fragment` esta no hace la notificacion ni la alarma correspondiente, se que hay captura de datos por que el TextView se carga con el `string` anterior diciendo "la alarma sonara a las 02:39" (ahorita en mi caso que es de madrugada) y luego de ese cambio en el `textview` ella no suena, no genera notificacion, naaaada...

Comment: Una idea es revisar los ejemplos de código en [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) aun que sean en ingles y tratar de implementar **algo** aun que quizás no funciona, luego hacer preguntas más concretas. La motivación de ayudarte sea con código o con traducciones de lo que no entiendes allá incrementa en forma increíble.

Comment: Modificado el post de una forma mas especifica  ( lamento el post anterior pero de verdad no tenia nada para defenderme o hacer pero gracias a la ayuda de @StefanNolde con ese link intente o medio trate de mejorar la situación, espero puedan ayudarme y no poner ninguna traba de mi parte)